# React.js: How to check after a props update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 4 form fields which a user can select or enter a value into, to advance to the next step. Here is one of those fields:

```
<Form.Field
  control={Checkbox}
  checked={this.props.donationCheckbox10}
  label='$10'
  value={10}
  onChange={() => {
    this.props.dispatchUpdateStateData('', 'donationInputField');
    this.props.dispatchUpdateStateData(!this.props.donationCheckbox10, 'donationCheckbox10');
    this.clearTheOtherCheckboxes(10);
    console.log(store.getState());
    this.checkIfReadyToAdvance();
  }}
/>
```

As you can see, it dispatches some actions to update a Redux store and then does a check to see if the user can advance.

The issue is that the advance condition always misses because the props have not updated and rerendered yet. At least I think this is the issue based on logging `this.checkIfReadyToAdvance()` (The getState() call returns the updated values because it doesn't wait for a rerender)

I believe `componentWillUpdate()` is being deprecated. What is the modern way to run a function after a Redux store updates the component?

Here is `checkIfReadyToAdvance()`

```
checkIfReadyToAdvance() {
    if (
      this.props.donationCheckbox10 ||
      this.props.donationCheckbox25 ||
      this.props.donationCheckbox50 ||
      this.props.donationInputField
    ) {
      this.setState({
        canNotAdvance : false
      });
      console.log("ready");
    } else {
      this.setState({
        canNotAdvance : true // in case all values are falsey again
      });
      console.log("not ready");
    }
  }
```

Comment: if `checkIfReadyToAdvance` calculates derived state, don't calculate it here. You can calculate everytime you rerender, you can calculate when props are changed or you can calculate in your store.

Comment: Thanks, can you post an example of one of them?

Comment: It would help if you showed us what `checkIfReadyToAdvance` actually does.

Comment: I will have posted that function to the original post. I got it working through componentDidUpdate() which I imagine is the best option here. Curious about how to implement it  on prop change or in the store if you could show either of those.

Comment: Well, it's derived state I wonder why do you even save it to state? Why not a function that will return a boolean and you call it instead of accessing state?

Comment: I'm trying to visualize your function but I just can't. I would think any function would still have to test the props for truthiness?

Answer (score 1):

There is little reason to store derived information unless the calculation of that information is performance heavy.

```
isReadyToAdvance() {
   const { props } = this;

   return
      props.donationCheckbox10 ||
      props.donationCheckbox25 ||
      props.donationCheckbox50 ||
      props.donationInputField;
}
```

and then just use `!this.isReadyToAdvance()` instead of `this.state.canNotAdvance`.

Technically, you could also use `componentWillUpdate` (deprecated) to update your `state` or the new [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).